# re-search-backward using (?:x)|(?:y) doesn't work?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to make an inferior mode derived from `comint-mode` automatically "linkify" two variations of `file:line:col` in the output.

To do so, I have one regexp with two subpatterns in non-capture groups, joined by `|`. Each subpattern has exactly three capture groups:

```
(concat
  "\\(?:" ;; pattern 1  e.g. "; /path/to/file:1:1"
    "; \\([^:]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)"
  "\\)"
  "\\|"
  "\\(?:" ;; pattern 2  e.g. "location:  #(<path:/path/to/file> 0 1"
    "location:   (#<path:\\([^>]+\\)> \\([0-9]+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)"
  "\\)")
```

The matches things matching the *first* subpattern. But it *never* matches things matching the *second* subpattern.

However the existence of the first pattern seems to mean that the second `(?: ...)` pattern will never match. If I comment out the first pattern, only then will the second one match.

If I remove the first subpattern, leaving

```
  "\\(?:" ;; pattern 2
    "location:   (#<path:\\([^>]+\\)> \\([0-9]+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)"
  "\\)"
```

it does match, so I know that the second subpattern is correct.

Or, if I retain a first subpattern but change it to be something like "XXX", with no captures:

```
  "\\(?:" ;; pattern 1
    "XXXX"
  "\\)"
  "\\|"
  "\\(?:" ;; pattern 2
    "location:   (#<path:\\([^>]+\\)> \\([0-9]+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)"
  "\\)"
```

it also works. The first subpattern doesn't match example input containing no "XXXX", and the second subpattern is tried next and does match.

I'm stumped. Am I misunderstanding something about regexps in general, or is this unique to Emacs?

---

More context in case it matters:

```
(define-derived-mode inferior-foo-mode comint-mode "Inferior Foo"
  ...
  (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'linkify)
  ...)

(defun linkify (str)
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-buffer)
    (re-search-backward (concat
                         "\\(?:" ;; pattern 1
                           "; \\([^:]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)"
                         "\\)"
                         "\\|"
                         "\\(?:" ;; pattern 2
                           "location:   (#<path:\\([^>]+\\)> \\([0-9]+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)"
                         "\\)")
                        (- (buffer-size) (length str))
                        t)
    (when (and (match-beginning 0)
               (match-beginning 1) (match-beginning 2) (match-beginning 3))
      (make-text-button
       (match-beginning 1) (match-end 3)
       'file (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1))
       'line (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2))
       'col  (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 3) (match-end 3))
       'action #'go-to-file-line-col
       'follow-link t))))
```

Comment: You might find [Re Builder](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReBuilder) and [rx](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/rx) useful

Comment: Definitely. In this case my regexp itself was actually correct, but in my code using the results I got stupid about the numbering of the capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting wrongly. The capturing groups for the second noncapturing group are `(match-string 4)`,  `(match-string 5)`, `(match-string 6)`,

Note also, that

```
(buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1))
```

is equivalent to the short clear version

```
(match-string-no-properties 1)
```

I would propose something like:

```
(let ((m1 (or (match-string-no-properties 1) (match-string-no-properties 4)))
      (m2 (or (match-string-no-properties 2) (match-string-no-properties 5)))
      (m2 (or (match-string-no-properties 3) (match-string-no-properties 6))))
     (when (and m1 m2 m3) ...
```

Comment: Yikes. Somehow I got the idea that the `|` would cause the second subpattern to be renumbered from 1, too. But clearly that would make no sense. Thank you also for the tip re `match-string-no-properties`.  BTW the code you added in your edit is almost exactly what I just wrote while trying your original answer. So, whew. The dummy pill seems to be wearing off now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp does not correspond to its comment.

The comment has `#(`; the regexp has `(#`.  The comment has two spaces after `location:`; the regexp has 3 spaces.  If you make them correspond then it seems to work fine.  E.g.:

```
(concat
 "\\(?:" ;; pattern 1
 "; \\([^:]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)"
 "\\)"
 "\\|"
 "\\(?:" ;; pattern 2
 "location:  #(<path:\\([^>]+\\)> \\([0-9]+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)"
 "\\)")
```

Comment: Good catch, but unfortunately that was a mistake I made adding the example at the last second. Sorry to mislead you and thank you for the answer which I'll upvote.